# Instantiating object in Python same as Java using jython

Tags: java, python, jython, instantiation

In **Java** I was able to run my code as:
(This are just sample naming)

```
import com.projectname.api.APIOne;
import com.projectname.api.APITwo;
import com.projectname.api.APIThree;
import com.projectname.api.APIFour;

import com.projectname.api.MainAPI;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        APIOne a = APIOne.getName();
        APITwo b = APIThree.getAddress();
        APIFour d = b.getEmail();

        MainAPI mainapi = new MainAPI();
        mainapi.setEmail(d)
    }
}
```

It is running okay, I tried converting this to **Python** as:

```
import com.projectname.api.APIOne as APIOne;
import com.projectname.api.APITwo as APITwo;
import com.projectname.api.APIThree as APIThree;
import com.projectname.api.APIFour as APIFour;

def test():

    a = APIOne.getName();
    b = APIThree.getAddress();
    d = b.getEmail();

    mainapi = MainAPI();
    mainapi.setEmail(d)

test()
```

But is this the right way of instantiating? It make me confuse on instantiating.

Hope you could help me.

Comment: When you say *instantiating*, are you talking about the Jython types or about the `TestMain`?

Comment: Instantiating of object @enrico.bacis, how can I make it similar as the instantiation the way I did in java. I don't wanna miss anything.

Comment: Ok, and what are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a class from a java package or python module is normally written as:

```
from java.lang import Math
```

Rather than:

```
import java.lang.Math as Math
```

But, your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are confused, but this is correct, you could check the [Jython documentation](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html) about instantiating Java objects using Jython and instantiates the objects the same way as you do.